# Cordova Camera --> CordovaWebView Timeout Error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, camera

I have a problem with opening the camere within a cordova android application. What I did was to define a simple button which calls a javascript function:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myClass" data-role="button" data-corners="false" onclick="makeNotificationPicture();"></a>
```

The function "makeNotificationPicture() only consists out of this:

```
function makeNotificationPicture(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoSuccess, null, {sourceType: 1, quality: 100});
}
```

When I start the application on my mobile device and press this button, I'm able to open the camera and make a picture. But afterwards ... when I try to get back to the application which should be done automatically I get an application error:

```
CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
CordovaWebViewClient.onReveicedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the
server was unsuccessful. URL=file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

I've already tried to add the following coding in the onCreate-Method:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

But this doesn't help...
Just for your information, I'm using Cordova-2.2.0.

I really hope that you can help me solving this problem.

Greetings and looking forward to your answers.
Stef

Comment: Do you have to use 2.2? Can you try on the latest version and see if you still get this error?

Comment: Hi again,

good news! I was able to solve the problem. In my phone I had the option "Don't keep activities logged" checked. Well then everything is clear...

I'm now able to make pictures and to receive the URI to them. It's always the following:

file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/MY-PACKAGE/chache/NUMBER.jpg

Is there a way to store them physically, because I cannot find them on my mobile phone. Looking forward to your answers!

Greetings Stef